# How to overwrite default command when running docker image

Tags: docker, containers

I'm trying to run my docker image and overwrite the default command node ./bin/name-of-program with:

```
docker run name/hub:4.5.0 /bin/bash
```

But isn't working. The default command is being executed and finishing the container:

```
2e9d10532e4c        name/hub:4.5.0   "node ./bin/name-of-program /bin/ba"   About a minute ago   Exited (1) About a minute ago                       insane_brown
```

Is it possible to access a container? I have a code inside that i losted.

Answer (score 0):

If the container defines an [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) command, that runs before the `CMD`.  Try:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash name/hub:4.5.0
```

The `-it` (aka `-i -t`) is necessary to get an interactive terminal; without that `bash` won't run.